# Selecting an img element on polymer element load

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have created a polymer element which has an `img` tag in it. I am using a javascript library(Vibrant.js) which basically picks up the dominant color from the image and gives out the color code. I am trying to select the image element in `attached` event of polymer. But somehow the image element is not getting selected to properly.

I get the following exception.

> Vibrant.min.js:1 Uncaught IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The source width is 0.

```
<dom-module id="my-image-block">
<template>
    <div class="service-wrapper">
        <div><img id="imgobject" src={{imagepath}}></div>
        <div class="service-wrapper-inner">
            <div>
                <p class="group-title">Stencil
                <p> <!--TODO : Remove hard coding-->
                    <div class="title">
                <p>Some content</p></div>
            <p class="last-modified">Last updated: {{lastmodified}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <p>{{description}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "my-image-block",
        attached: function () {
            var self = this;
            var imageobject = self.$.imgobject;
            var vibrant = new Vibrant(imageobject, 64, 6);
            var swatches = vibrant.swatches();
            var backColor = swatches["Vibrant"].getHex()
            $(".service-wrapper-inner").css("background-color", backColor);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: the problem is not with polymer. If you log `imageobject` on console you should be able to see valid object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do that by calling a function on `on-load` event of `img` object.

```
<!-- rest of the code-->
<div><img id="image-object" src={{imagepath}} on-load="handleImageObjectOnLoad"></div>
<!-- rest of the code-->
```

And for the polymer code i did something like this.

```
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "marketplace-image-block",
        handleImageObjectOnLoad: function () {
            var self = this;
            var imageobject = self.$['image-object'];
            var vibrant = new Vibrant(imageobject, 64, 5);
            var swatches = vibrant.swatches();
            var backColor = swatches["Vibrant"].getHex();
            self.customStyle["--custom-background-color"] = backColor;
            self.updateStyles();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Where `--custom-background-color` is a css styling variable.

```
<style>
        :host{
            --custom-background-color: grey;
        }
.service-wrapper-inner {
    background-color: var(--custom-background-color);
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error can be resolved by giving `width` and `height` to the image tag.

```
<template>
 <style>
  #imgobject{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
  }
 </style>
 <!-- rest of your code -->
```

But even after that i was not able to make it run now i got a new error

> Vibrant.js:651 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

On further debugging i found that this error was coming because of an unhandled error in vibrant which was being generated due to the fact that [cmap](https://github.com/jariz/vibrant.js/blob/master/dist/Vibrant.js#L651) wa coming as `false` rather than an object as expected. This was happening because when the js disintegrated image and read `rgba` value of each pixel it got 0 as value, as a result it did not [push](https://github.com/jariz/vibrant.js/blob/master/dist/Vibrant.js#L632-L647) anything in `allpixels` array.

I tried with images from vibrant example also but no success.